# Is there a SQL value "DifferentThan" comparison method

Tags: sql, syntax, null, compare

I was certain there was something like a "DifferentThan" method in SQL.
I am not looking for the `<>` operator, which will fail `NULL` comparisons.

For example, imagine a nullable bit column.

When checking for "not true" I could do something like this

```
WHERE COALESCE(myBit,0) = 0
```

and perhaps this is the best way... I'm not really interested in that. I'm particularly *trying to remember* the syntax for something like "DIFFERENTTHAN"

```
WHERE myBit DIFFERENTTHAN 1
```

EDIT: I've answered my own question below.

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you using?  The only way around your problem that I've every seen is the COALESCE trick, which, as you've said, is something you want to avoid.

Comment: @Joel Brown It's not so much that I want to *avoid* `COALESCE` but more that I want to remember this particular syntax I've seen before.

Comment: FWIW, I've never heard of such a keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is

```
IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM
```

Which is in the ANSI standard but **not** included in MSSQLServer

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/is-not-distinct-from

Answer (score 1):

For **standard** ANSI/ISO SQL, null behaviour is rather strictly defined. In a nutshell:

- All expressions involving `NULL` values evaluate to `NULL`, except for `coalesce()`.
- All tests involving `NULL` values fail, except for **explicit tests for nullity**. The following fail:

  - `X = null`
  - `null = null`
  - `X < null`
  - etc.

  Essentially, `NULL` is a value that lies outside the domain of the variable. This means that inverse comparison operators are not symmetric WRT to `NULL`.

All of the expressions below, if a null is involved, fail and null values fall through.

```
* `X < null`
* `X >= null`
* `X > null`
* `not ( X > null )`
* etc.

In standard SQL, test for `null`/`not null`, one **must** use `IS [NOT] NULL`.
```

In your case, to have a test succeed if a value is null you can do things like:

- `where ( A = B or B is null )`.
  This will will fail is A is null and B is non-null, or A and B are non-null and compare unequal. It succeed if A and B are non-null and compare equal, or if B is null.
- `where A = coalesce(B,A)`. This behaves the same as the above expression. I tend to prefer it as the syntax is more concise.

Note that some SQL implementations allow for null behaviour that differs from the standard (MS/Sybase Transact-SQL for instance, has the option to allow testing for nullity with standard comparision operators, and allowing null `char`/`varchar` to behave as if they were nil (empty) strings. In earlier versions of SQL Server, nullity was implemented by making the column variable length, regardless of its type. A null value was stored with zero length. For `char`/`varchar` fields, a nil (empty) string was stored as a single space. Not exactly intuitive. As side effect, a declaration like `foo char(8) null` was the equivalent of declaring it `foo varchar(8) null`.

Even if your SQL implementation supports non-standard null behaviour, you should avoid it and code as if it were standard SQL with ANSI nulls behaviour. In most implementations that support non-standard null behaviour, that behaviour is configurable via a runtime option. You standard coding will yield the same results regardless of whether you're running under standard ANSI nulls behaviour or not.

Comment: You answer seems in contrast to the solution posed by Itzik Ben-Gan in the link posted in my answer.

Comment: Since I've never seen an implementation of IS DISTINCT FROM in the wild &mdash;neither SQL Server, DB2 nor Oracle support it &mdash; I have to file that particular SQL99 language feature as "would be nice to have". Since I can't write code that utilized hypothetical language features, like most people, I'm stuck using compound conditions with `IS [NOT] NULL` to achieve my desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
WHERE NOT myBit = 1
```

which isn't a single operator, but is a bit cleaner than using COALESCE.

Comment: This doesn't work either. It fails `NULL` comparisons in the same way as `<>`. To test: `SELECT 'test' WHERE NOT 1 = NULL`

Comment: NULL = 1 evaluates to false, which gives us NOT FALSE, which is TRUE. therefore it returns TRUE for any value other than 1.

Comment: I believe in three-valued logic, NULL = 1 evaluates to NULL.